# Can't install Windows 10 on desktop PC: "We couldn't create a new partition"

Tags: windows, partitioning, installation, usb-flash-drive

I can't install Windows 10 (or 7) on my desktop PC and keep seeing the error:

> We couldn't create a new partition

I had my Windows 7 (not licensed, but activated) for a very long time, and didn't really take much care of it. Recently, Skype started to unlog with disk error, google-read fix with profile deletion didn't help (it started again), also, DotA 2 game sometimes just crashed, browser pages had huuuuuge delay.

I decided to install other Windows, erasing everything completely. I firstly made bootable DVD-RW with Windows 7 image from some tracker (it was stated that it is original MSDN image), it failed, but I don't remember if it did with the same error or not.

Then I picked my JetFlash Transcend 4GB and made it bootable Windows 10 with the help of Microsoft Media Tool or something. And I just constantly get the error.

I firstly realized that I had some USB peripherals, and I unplugged everything except power, DVI for monitor, speakers and PS/2 keyboard and mouse.

I don't have any SD or whatever. My S.M.A.R.T thing in BIOS is disabled.

I tried, in various combinations and sequential orders:

1. To DISKPART things up with easily googleable instructions;
2. To disable legacy storage thing in BIOS, then shut down PC, plug flash drive in other port, turn on PC, enable legacy in BIOS and go on.
3. Disabling/enabling various SATA and USB 2.0 stuff (btw, I have maximum USB 2.0)

Approximately half a year ago, I tested my HDD with a software, there was crushed sector, but only one, I think.

I should really know whether it's an old-old HDD issue before spending money on new HDD.

My relevant PC configuration and firmware below (PC, except for graphic card, is very old):

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-EP35-DS3, DDR2 RAM
- Processor: Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600
- HDD: WDC WD5000AAKS-65YGA0

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29170/discussion-on-question-by-a-russian-guy-cant-install-windows-10-and-as-it-see).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on one of my computers. It has 3 hard drives, and 2 BD-REs. I had to unplug two of the three hard drives to get Windows 10 to install.

The downside is, that after I got Windows 10 up and running (activation was complete), when I booted after plugging in other two drives, Windows 10 was no longer activated. I called Microsoft support which landed me at Tier 2 tech support. When Tier 2 called me and I explained what happened, I was told that was normal for Windows 10. If you change to much hardware, your hash value changes and it deactivates. The good news is that Tier 2 was able to issue me a new license key (after verifying my old key was **valid and legal**) and Windows 10 is once again activated.